# Purchase domain and web-hosting from different company

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I know that it is possible to purchase domain from one company and web-hosting from other, but I have never done that yet. Its first time I am doing it so I want to do it in correct way. 
 I have domain registered within **company A**. And I have now purchased web-hosting from **company B**. From my understanding all I have to set are domain name servers for my domain in **company A** pointing to DNS servers of **company B**.

But how the **company B** knows that I am real owner of this domain. What If someone already purchased web-hosting for this domain in **company B**. It means that I would not be able then to purchase webhosting from this company for my domain? Or how does it work?

Comment: It is the registrar that is the enforcement of the domain name, not the web host. The web host does not care about domain names except to tie it to a web space so they know how to handle in coming requests.

Comment: Well thats the point, upon purchasing of web hosting I was asked for domain name. So I typed my domain. But what if someone has already purchased web-hosting for this domain name, but does not own this domain? It means I won't able to order web-hosting for this domain in this particular company anymore because someone else did?

Comment: I cannot speak for your experience, however, before retiring, I was a web host as a part of my business. I started in the industry so early that I was one of the very first registered ISPs and a principle expert in the industries first trade shows. That said, the web host sells web space but must know the domain name so that web requests can be properly directed to the right space. Some web hosts are also registrars and allow you to register a domain name. GoDaddy is an example. How your host handle things? I cannot say. Sometimes these things get blurry trying to make it all user friendly.

Comment: Well I just tried to purchase another web-hosting for same hostname and their page won't allow me so yeah it is little blurry... thanks anyway. I was not sure if I have to do anything else like proving ownership of domain beside changing name server because my mind could not get around this problem.

Comment: @Ľubomír Whomever is the admin for a domain is the only one that can change the name servers for it. You can't order and setup hosting for a domain with a hosting provider without changing the name servers to them - the setup will fail since they're not able to modify your DNS. Another party therefore cannot purchase and setup hosting for your domain because _you_ control the name servers. Once the hosting provider confirms that their name servers are being used for your domain, they can then setup DNS records pointing to their servers. So you did things the correct/only way in that scenario.

Comment: This is rarely a problem.   It would be a very sophisticated attack to figure out where you will be hosting and per-emptively create an account with that domain name.   If that did happen, you could always call up the hosts tech support and ask them to resolve the problem.   They could tell who is the real owner of the domain name by asking you to add specific special DNS records.

Comment: DNS hosting potentially has the same issue.   Here is a question about the feasability of a similar attack at Amazon's Route 53 DNS service: [Route 53 on AWS, Whats stopping me from using someone elses domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107469/route-53-on-aws-whats-stopping-me-from-using-someone-elses-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you've mentioned, the hosting and the domain are two completely separate things.

In your case, Company B doesn't care. It just provides the storage and the environment. When you point your domain to your hosting (by changing the name servers), you need to go to your hosting configuration (most often in the form of a control panel such as CPanel) and assign the domain to point to a folder in your hosting account. That's it.

You do raise a good point though - what if you're using a shared hosting and there are other people on the same server? Can someone maybe hijack a subdomain of yours that you haven't yet assigned to your account?

Sometimes the answer is yes. This can happen if you create a wildcard `A` record for your domain so that `*.yourdomain.tld` points to your host's IP address. Now it's up to the control panel to allow or forbid that someone else to perform that action - you can't be certain that the panel will tell them "Uh-oh, looks like you're trying to point another client's domain to your folder".

And let's look at one final case. Let's assume that you and I are used the same shared hosting provider and somehow ended up on the same server. I used to own `mydomain.com`, and it's pointed to a folder under my hosting account. But it has expired and you bought it, and now you want it to point to your folder. That's when an unexpected result can occur (meaning it could point to my folder again while you're the owner of the domain), but you can always poke the support, and I'm sure they would assist you. And the chances for that are extremely slim, as you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

> But how the company B knows that I am real owner of this domain.

Company B hosting company is not tied at all to domain names, Company A holds the registration and DNS settings.

> What If someone already purchased web-hosting for this domain in company B.

Domains can only be registered for one company/individual, when you purchase that domain it is your for the remainder of the registration term.

> It means that I would not be able then to purchase webhosting from
> this company for my domain? Or how does it work?

You can purchase hosting from any company that you which, you can even host your setting from own computer if you have a static IP address.

## Domains

When you purchase a domain, it gets registered with that company(the domain registrar) that company sends all the domains they have registered to the domain name registries.

### DNS settings

Keeping it simple DNS settings routes visitors from your domain name to your Server.

## Hosting

Keeping it they provide servers to host your site So go to your domain registrar and change the DNS settings to point to your hosting server on the other company.